# How to select a input field in next TD with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select a input field in next TD with Jquery. I can not use ID or class because the table's row can be add or removed.

like ,

```
 <tr>
<td><input type='text' name='price[]' onkeyup = 'getTest(this)' /> </td>
<td><input type='text' name='qty[]' onkeyup = 'getPrice(this)' value='1' /> </td>
<td><input type='text' name='amount[]' /> </td>
</tr>

function getTest(obj){
//I want to select qty[] and amount[]
}

function getPrice(obj){
//I want to select price[] and amount[]
}
```

anybody know how to select the input fields, please help~!

Thanks

Comment: Don't use inline events like onkeyup, let jquery do all the work in the actual jquery script.

Comment: Also, rephrase your question title, it's not a real question and helps nobody if they try and search!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`working demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/TRMxh/1/)  of your expected behavior of your webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Chinmayee's answer is much better than this one, but if you don't want to change any of your HTML mark-up, you can simply drop this into your JavaScript and it will work:

```
    function getTest(obj) {
        var tr = $(obj).closest('tr');
        var qty = tr.find('input[name="qty[]"]');
        var amount = tr.find('input[name="amount[]"]');

        console.log('qty: ' + qty.val());
        console.log('amount: ' + amount.val());

    }

    function getPrice(obj) {
        var tr = $(obj).closest('tr');
        var price = tr.find('input[name="price[]"]');
        var amount = tr.find('input[name="amount[]"]');

        console.log('price: ' + price.val());
        console.log('amount: ' + amount.val());
    }
```

But the reason why Chinmayee's answer is better than mine is because it uses unobtrusive JavaScript, and it also uses event delegation, so it will perform better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution for your problem (assuming you want *amount* to be *price* * *qty*):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[name="price[]"], [name="qty[]"]').live('keyup', function(){
    var inputs = $(this).closest('tr').find('input');
    $(inputs[2]).val($(inputs[0]).val()*$(inputs[1]).val());
  });
});
```

Your getTest() and getPrice() methods are no longer required with this solution and you can also drop the `onkeyup="..."` attributes on the `input` elements.

[See here](http://jsbin.com/okene5) for a working demo.